# In moongose If I am creating a schema with 4 fields. But I am saving values of two fields only. How to update the field values that are not given?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, rest

If my schema has username location phone number mail
By post request I gave a json object with username and location
Is there any possibility to add the phonenumber and mail using findbyIdandupdate() in mongoose

Comment: yes you can update at a later time

Answer (score 0):

```
router.post('/updateUser', (req, res) => {
  const { id, update } = req.body;
  schema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, (err) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err})
    return res.json({ success: true })
  })
})
```

You could test the request with an app like Postman or Insomnia